# Asus G74 blocking Ubuntu LTS install

Tags: asus

I am trying to install Ubuntu LTS on my laptop (Asus G74), but when i select the Usb drive I'm using, a black screen with white text appears. It says something wn-block at the top.

Comment: Could you please tell us what it says exactly? It's hard to debug without the actual error messages.

Comment: wn-block(0,0)
[     1.817966] CPU: 5 PID: 1 comm: swapper/o Not tainted 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
[     1.818026] Hardware name: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. G74Sx/G74Sx, Bios G74Sx.201 04/27/2011

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to disable secureboot as it thinks ubuntu is a rootkit or some other unverified bootloader trying to install itself. Disable secureboot from the uefi settings and try again.